# true or false boolean expressions, when to put the NOT operator?

Tags: java, boolean, conditional-statements, boolean-expression

So i've been asked to code a boolean expression for numbers between -15 and 50 inclusive, where it is **not** odd between 10 and 20 inclusive.

```
n = 21;
b1 = (n>=-15 && n<=50);
b2 = (n % 2 != 0) && (n>=10 && (n<=20));
result = b1 && !b2;
```

I am not sure why we can't write it as boolean `b2 = (n % 2==0) && (n>=10 && n<=20)`. I'm a bit confused here. can someone clarify please.

Comment: Maybe it's worth reading about DeMorgan's laws to get to the result? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

In general code inspection says it's a code-smell if you need to negate a boolean, because then you could've rewritten the conditions. It makes more sense if you give them meaningful names, not just `b1`, `b2`

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it step by step using if-else statements

```
if ( n >= -15 && n <= 50 ) {
  if ( n >= 10 && n <= 20 ) {
    if ( n % 2 == 0 ) {
      // true
    }
  } else { // = if ( n < 10 || n > 20 )
    // true
  }
}
```

Is equal to:

```
b1 = (n >= -15 && n <= 50) && (n >= 10 && n <= 20) && (n % 2 == 0)
b2 = (n >= -15 && n <= 50) && (n < 10 || n > 20)
result = b1 || b2
```

Now you can extract the common parts:

```
common = (n >= -15 && n <= 50)
b1 = common && (n >= 10 && n <= 20) && (n % 2 == 0)
b2 = common && (n < 10 || n > 20)
result = b1 || b2

// =>

common = (n >= -15 && n <= 50)
b1 = (n >= 10 && n <= 20) && (n % 2 == 0)
b2 = (n < 10 || n > 20)
result = common && (b1 || b2)
```

We also know that `b1` and `b2` can never be `true` at the same time, because their number ranges don't overlap (`b1` is between 10 and 20, and `b2` is everything else). Though we can shorten the statement even further, utilizing the short-circuit nature of boolean OR expressions:

```
common = (n >= -15 && n <= 50)
b1 = (n % 2 == 0)
b2 = (n < 10 || n > 20)
result = common && (b2 || b1) // notice: b1 and b2 have been swapped
```

As code:

```
if (n >= -15 && n <= 50) {
  if (n < 10 || n > 20) {
    // true
  } else {
    // this will only happen if n is between -15 and 50, AND if n is NOT < 10 OR > 20
    // in other words:  if n is between 10 and 20
    if ( n % 2 == 0 ) {
      // true
    }
  }
}
```

Using De Morgan's law a boolean OR expression becomes this:

```
( (n < 10 || n > 20) || (n % 2 == 0) )
// =>
! ( !(n < 10 || n > 20) && !(n % 2 == 0) ) 
// which can be transformed again using De Morgan's law =>
! ( (n >= 10 && n <= 20) && (n % 2 != 0) )
```

So the end result is:

```
common = (n >= -15 && n <= 50)
b1 = (n % 2 == 0)
b2 = (n < 10 || n > 20)
result = common && (b2 || b1)
result = (n >= -15 && n <= 50) && ((n < 10 || n > 20) || (n % 2 == 0))

// apply De Morgan's law =>
result = common && !(!b2 && !b1)
result = (n >= -15 && n <= 50) && !( (n >= 10 && n <= 20) && (n % 2 != 0) )
```

It's kinda like math, but with boolean values: [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)